# How to run one statement after another in a procedural manner in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, procedural

Lets say we have a simple scenario where I would like to repeatedly output "Hello" followed by "World" 1 second later. I have tried the following:

```
setInterval(
    function() {
        console.log("Hello");

        setTimeout(
            function() {
                console.log("World");
            },
            1000
        );
    },
    1000 
);
```

But it doesn't work, at the second interation of `setInterval` the `console.log` outputs Hello  World at the same time.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think you should be using `setTimeout()`, not `setInterval()`

Comment: He's using both. Each event fired with `setInterval` also results in a one-time event fired with `setTimeout`.

Comment: What happens when you increase the setInterval time to 1100? At the moment, since both are 1000 it's not guaranteed which will happen first.

Comment: In that case setTimer time should be 1100 / 2 = 550

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outer interval should be 2 seconds.

Comment: @chutsu, not this is not stupidity, maybe just lack of coffee ))

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but I think its useful in your situation,

I created a `queue runner` function that takes a list of functions to run after a period of time

**Features:**

- You can add as many as you want functions to the queue
- You can set if you want to run the queue once or to repeat the sequence
- Using only the `setInterval` function and without the `setTimeout`

**Definition:**

```
var queue = function ( /* Array<function> */ fn, /* int */ timeout, /* boolean */ repeat) {
    return function () {
        var i = 0,
            f = fn[i],
            t = setInterval(function () {
                f();
                if (fn[i + 1] !== undefined) {
                    f = fn[++i];
                } else {
                    if (repeat) {
                        i = 0;
                        f = fn[i];
                    } else {
                        clearInterval(t);
                    }
                }
            }, timeout);
    }
}
```

And you call it like this :

```
var fn = [function(){console.log('A')}, function(){console.log('B')}];
queue(fn, 1000, true)();
```

**JSFIDDLE:**

you can check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadmoussawi/NrL98/1/)
Hope this help ☺